# Counting the Frequencies of Words in Excel Strings

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I have a column of arbitrary length where each cell contains a string of text.  Is there a way to determine what words appear most frequently in the column (not knowing in advance which words to check) and subsequently order these words along with their frequencies in a two column table?  Would VBA be best for this task?

As an example, a cell might contain the string "This is a string, and the # of characters inthis string is>0." (errors intentional)

Comment: Have you tried the built in subtotals tool?

Comment: subtotal tool does exactly what you want. You select the column, and select the function to use (probably count) and select the column to put the subtotal in. so it counts the appearances of each different word, and also gives a grand total. the only thing, you do have to sort by the column you want or subtotal doesnt really work

Comment: Hold your horses, I've got the answer to this in two words... Pivot table! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Select a portion of column **A** and run this small macro ( the table will be placed in cols. **B** & **C**  :

```
Sub Ftable()
    Dim BigString As String, I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
    BigString = ""
```

' Add code to sum both "All" and "all"
' Add code to separate "." "!" etc. from the word preceeding them so that word
' is also counted in the total. For example: "all." should not be reported as 1 ' "all." but "all" be added to the total count of "all" words.
' Would you publish this new code?

```
    For Each r In Selection 
          BigString = BigString & " " & r.Value
    Next r
    BigString = Trim(BigString)
    ary = Split(BigString, " ")
    Dim cl As Collection
    Set cl = New Collection
    For Each a In ary
        On Error Resume Next
        cl.Add a, CStr(a)
    Next a

    For I = 1 To cl.Count
        v = cl(I)
        Cells(I, "B").Value = v
        J = 0
        For Each a In ary
            If a = v Then J = J + 1
        Next a
        Cells(I, "C") = J
    Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: From what I can tell your macro worked perfectly, thank you!  Is there any possible way you could provide intuition for what is happening?  I understand some but not all of the macro.

Comment: The macro first creates a very long string of words separated by spaces.  **Split** creates an array of separate words.  The **Collection** builds a group of unique words.  These uniques are placed in column **B** and the associated counts are placed in column **C**

Comment: Thanks Gary, I'm also curious as to why it sometimes splits word counts.  For example the 'word' 0 is listed twice - the first listing having a frequency of 12 and the second having a frequency of 4.  I checked and they seem to be of the same data type.

Comment: Make sure there are no extra spaces between the words and the spelling is exactly the same.

Comment: Applying Excel's TRIM function on the Big String before splitting will help deal with extra spaces. You can use the Dictionary object to get a unique list as well. Dictionary object has an isExists method to test whether a work exists in the collection before adding it; so you do not have to rely on ON ERROR RESUME NEXT.

Answer (score 5):

Given this:

[image]

I'll use a pivot table to get this:

[image]

Best part is, if I got more, it's easy to get Top 5, 10, etc. And it'll always result to unique indices. From there, there are all manners of editing and calculation you can do. :)

Comment: This is helpful, but what if there are multiple words in every cell?

Comment: By `multiple words in every cell`, what exactly do you mean? Sentences, delimited values, etc. Kindly post an example in your post above. :)

Comment: Added an example as requested, thanks for reminding me to do so.

Comment: Based on your example, the best way is @Gary'sStudent's solution. Try it and you'll be surprised. :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm just looking at that now.  I just realized I didn't fully answer your question.  It would be possible to delimit the strings as well so that we have a two dimensional array to count.  The only issue would then be, without knowing all the words, to make the two column table of words and their frequencies from that array.

Answer (score 2):

Using Google Sheets:

```
index((Transpose(ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ",$B$2)," ")&{"";""}),"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc limit 20 label Col1 'Word', count(Col2) 'Frequency'",0)))),1,$A6+1)&":"&index((Transpose(ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(" ",$B$2)," ")&{"";""}),"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc limit 20 label Col1 'Word', count(Col2) 'Frequency'",0)))),2,$A6+1)
```

In the above $B$2 contains the text string

$A6 = 1 will give you the most used word

$A6 = 2 will give you the second most used word
etc.

This is set to do 20 most frequent. If you want more, increase the limit value to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tiny fix plus an enhancement to the script kindly offered by "Gary's Student".  The fix is that while building the collection is apparently not case-sensitive (and this is correct--we probably don't want new items added to the collection that differ only in case from existing items), the IF statement that does the counting IS case-sensitive as written, so it doesn't count correctly.  Just change that line to...

```
If LCase(a) = LCase(v) Then J = J + 1
```

And here's my enhancement.  To use it, you first select one or more columns but NOT their (first) header/label rows.  Then run the script, and it gives results for each selected column in a new worksheet--along with that header/label row so you know what you're looking at.

I'm just a dabbler. I just hack stuff when I need to get a job done, so it's not elegant, I'm sure...

```
Sub FrequencyV2() 'Modified from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858874/counting-the-frequencies-of-words-in-excel-strings
'It determines the frequency of words found in each selected column.
'Puts results in new worksheets.
'Before running, select one or more columns but not the header rows.
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim col As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsNumber As Long 'Used to put a number in the names of the newly created worksheets
    wsNumber = 1
    Set rng = Selection
    For Each col In rng.Columns
        Dim BigString As String, I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
        BigString = ""
        For Each cell In col.Cells
            BigString = BigString & " " & cell.Value
        Next cell
        BigString = Trim(BigString)
        ary = Split(BigString, " ")
        Dim cl As Collection
        Set cl = New Collection
        For Each a In ary
            On Error Resume Next 'This works because an error occurs if item already exists in the collection.
            'Note that it's not case sensitive.  Differently capitalized items will be identified as already belonging to collection.
            cl.Add a, CStr(a)
        Next a
        Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = "F" & CStr(wsNumber)
        wsNumber = wsNumber + 1
        Worksheets(ws.Name).Cells(1, "A").Value = col.Cells(1, 1).Offset(-1, 0).Value 'Copies the table header text for current column to new worksheet.
        For I = 1 To cl.Count
            v = cl(I)
            Worksheets(ws.Name).Cells(I + 1, "A").Value = v 'The +1 needed because header text takes up row 1.
            J = 0
            For Each a In ary
                If LCase(a) = LCase(v) Then J = J + 1
            Next a
            Worksheets(ws.Name).Cells(I + 1, "B") = J 'The +1 needed because header text takes up row 1.
        Next I
    Next col
End Sub
```