# Count frequency of words in a list

Tags: vba, excel

I start by saying that I am not an expert user of VBA; I am just learning it.

I have a question regarding the possibility of counting text strings in Excel using a Macro. I cannot use the 'Countif' function, as there are more than 20,000 text strings in the Excel file, and it would be a lengthy procedure I guess.

I was therefore thinking about the possibility of using a VBA code to scan and organize text strings by their frequencies.

For instance, there are a set of words like this in my file (each in a different cell):

home,
balcony,
flat,
apartment,
home,
home,
garden,
thing,
revenue,
flat,
...
window

I would like to know if there's a way to make Excel scan all the different text strings and come back with the frequency for each of them.

I am aware that probably there are easier way to do it (e.g. Python or some add ins), but we have to do it at work, and I can't really ask my colleagues to learn Python or other programming languages, nor we have the capability to buy any software at the moment.

Thanks to those who can help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858874/counting-the-frequencies-of-words-in-excel-strings

Comment: For a single string entry per cell just use a pivot table.

Comment: Use a countif, 20000 values should not be a problem at all, just select the entire column.  if you reeeeeeeeally wanrt to maker this difficult, you could: read the values into a variant array, take a dictionary approach to record totals per word, loop through recordset to add to dictionary, loop again to print values.  EDIT: brets answer is perfect for what you need

Answer (score 3):

Simple Pivot Table (without VBA - but could be code if needed)

See [Debra's](http://www.contextures.com/about.html) great website

[image]

Comment: Thanks brettdj! the issue with my original file is that I have no idea of all the 22k words in the Excel file (apologies, I think I have not made it clear enough). I think that to compile the 'row labels' in your example I will have to know or count the unique values in my file; however, as far as I know, there might be even 10k unique values in my file, therefore it would be extremely difficult to go through each value and see which are duplicates and which are unique values. That's why I wanted to find something that could 'automatically' scan all the cells and then count the frequencies

Comment: @mark no - the output is automatic based on the range :) You don't need to make a list of the unique records, that is automatic.